# Как вырованять legend по середине fieldset?

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток, возник вопрос. Как выровнять `legend` по центру `fieldset`?

Нагуглил такой способ:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Текст</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Так же пробовал делать при помощи `text-align: center;` и `margin-left: 50%; tranform: translateY(-50%);` но не вышло то, что нужно.

Но сейчас, вроде как, пользоваться такими атрибутами - плохой тон. Есть другие способы?

Comment: `align="center"` - это тот же `text-align:center` - `legend[Attributes Style] {
    text-align: center;
}`  `text-align:center` выравнивает правильно http://prntscr.com/ijyu0k

Comment: будет не лишний указать средство просмотра в котором не работает

Comment: @Алекс, я конкретно про это align="center", что плохой тон, вроде как

Comment: минус может быть в плохой кроссбраузерности некоторых тегов, но не всех тегов. комментарий выше относится к сообщению *Так же пробовал делать при помощи text-align: center; и margin-left: 50%; tranform: translateY(-50%); но не вышло то, что нужно.* т.е. если не устраивает атрибут, вы можете css прописать `legend{text-align:center}` и это работает.

Comment: @Alex, я попробовал, не работает

Comment: а в чем вы пробовали ? ссылка на скриншот в первом комментарии.

Comment: @Alex, jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5oa656ww/ проблемы нет, выравнивание по горизонтали работает правильно.

Comment: @Alex, http://prntscr.com/ijzj69 - Firefox, последняя версия

Answer (score 1):

```css
fieldset {
  text-align: center;
}

legend {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Текст</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1** - минус в том, что ячейка на всю ширину и перекрывает границу `fieldset`:

```css
fieldset>legend {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Fix using absolute and transform</legend>
</fieldset>
```

---

1. [Подобный вопрос на so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27124746/5398808)
2. [Оригинал ответа 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27124747/5398808)